# How to change icon using ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to change the icon using the jquery and ajax call. I have this function that let any logged in user like or unlike the image. So to do that I am using jquery's click event to get the URL of the function and then using ajax I am trying to change the icon.
Here is the detailed code:

```html
<a href="#" class="pull-right nogo" 
  data-url="{% url 'favorite' song.id %}"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></a>
```

```js
$('.nogo').on('click', function () {
    var url = $(this).attr('data-url');
    console.log(url);
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: url,
        success: function () {
            icon = $(this).find("i");
            icon.toggleClass("icon-circle-arrow-up icon-circle-arrow-down");
            console.log('done');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.nogo').on('click', function () {
    var url = $(this).attr('data-url');
    console.log(url);
    var _this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: url,
        success: function () {
            icon = _this.find("i");
            icon.toggleClass("fa-heart fa-heart-o");
            console.log('done');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As Taplar mentioned: there is a probably a problem with 'this'

Can you try this?

```
$('.nogo').on('click', function (e) {
    var url = $(this).attr('data-url');
    // Uses the click event to get where clicked.
    // And create a jQuery object of it.
    var target = $(e.target)
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: url,
        success: function () {
            target.toggleClass("icon-circle-arrow-up icon-circle-arrow-down");
            console.log('done');
        }
    });
});
```